# How to make placeholder display an int variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form>
<?php 
    echo 
    "<script>
        quant = $item_quant;
    </script>";
?>
<input type="number" name="quant" class="quant" placeholder="{{ quant }}">
</form>
```

I tried using "{{ quant }}" but the numbers initially flicker and don't display. I'm basically setting script variable quant to equal php variable $item_quant and then making html input placeholder to equal the value of quant. Any ideas? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how JS (or HTML) works.

You do not need JS here

```html
<form>
<input type="number" name="quant" class="quant" placeholder="{{ $item_quant }}">
</form>
```

or

```
<form>
<input type="number" name="quant" class="quant" placeholder="<?= $item_quant ?>">
</form>
```

If you insist on JS, then this. Note the placeholder will contain a PHP string in this snippet until you put it on your server

```html
<?php ... ?>
<script>
const quant =  `<?=  $item_quant ?>`;
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('.quant').placeholder = quant;
});
</script>
<form>
<input type="number" name="quant" class="quant" placeholder="">
</form>
```